# How to correct an accidental "table overflow"?

Tags: html, css, html-table

I am currently coding an accessibility page, but I am visually impaired. I've been advised that the table on this page:

http://www.accessibilityagent.com/legal/

is overlapping the adjacent content. Below is the CSS code being used. Could someone please help adjust this code to not overlap the page in the link above:

---

```
<div>
  <style type="text/css">
    body {
      color: purple;
      background-color: #d8da3d
    }
    table.center {
      margin-left:auto; 
      margin-right:auto;
    }
    body {
      text-align:center;
    }
    table {
     width: 50%;
    }
    table, th, td {
      border: 20px solid black;
      margin: auto;
      padding: 5px;
    }
    td.wrappable,
    table.data_table td.wrappable {
      white-space: normal;
    }
  </style>
```

Comment: Hi Mario, this question actually has nothing to do with Craft. As such, we'll migrate it over to Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 2):

Try setting this CSS for the table:

```
table-layout: fixed;
width: 100%;
word-wrap: break-word;
```

Answer (score 1):

you need to fit the `table`, so set `table-layout:fixed` , now you need to have it fit as large as possible so change `width` to `100%` in `table`, then you need to fit the links in the cell, so break the words, using `word-wrap:break-word` in `.center a`

```css
body {
  background-color: #d8da3d;
  color: purple;
}
table.center {
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  table-layout: fixed;
  width: 100%;
}
table,
th,
td {
  border: 20px solid black;
  padding: 5px;
}
.center a {
  display: block;
  word-wrap: break-word;
}
```

```html
<table class="center">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th scope="col">Year</th>
      <th scope="col">Plaintiff</th>
      <th scope="col">Defendant</th>
      <th scope="col">Link to More Info</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td scope="row">2015</td>
      <td>US DOJ</td>
      <td>YAKIMA COUNTY</td>
      <td><a href="http://www.ada.gov/yakima_co_pca/yakima_sa.html">http://www.ada.gov/yakima…</a>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```